# External (CDN hosted) image request URL rewritten in IE8 on canvas page over https, asks for proxy.php

Tags: iframe, https, external, cdn, facebook-canvas

I have a canvas-based app on Facebook wit **a lot** of images to load, so I'm creating them  in JavaScript.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = document.location.protocol + '//example.cloudfront.net/example_path/example.png';
```

The images are hosted on Amazon's CDN, their base URL is similar to:

```
https://example.cloudfront.net/example_path/example.png
```

The URL of the app, hosted in a cloud (EC2, also Amazon) is similar to:

```
https://cloud.example.com/path_to_app/
```

It works on most browsers, but not in IE (8).

In IE, if I inspect the *src* property of a created image, it shows the correct URL, but the browser makes the following request:

```
GET /path_to_app/proxy.php?url=https://example.cloudfront.net/example_path/example.png HTTPS/1.1
```

There is no *proxy.php* on my server, nor is the word 'proxy' present anywhere in my code, neither client- nor server-side.

Is there something I don't know about externally hosted content in an iframe canvas page, served over https?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I'm using *flashcanvas* in IE to emulate the <canvas> element. There are cross-domain asset access security issues with Flash, so the applet requests them via a proxy php script (actually included in the distribution, lol).

Trouble was, the flashcanvas source code is minimized/obfuscated, so the string 'proxy' is not visible.